# Using NetBeans for pure HTML/JS/CSS development

Tags: php, html, css, netbeans, local

Is it possible to use NetBeans to create HTML/JS/CSS projects which can be run by a local web browser instead of a full PHP project which has to be passed through an interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes. You would build the program in nearly the same way, but just open the source HTML file directly in your browser as a file instead of accessing it from the webserver Netbeans is using.

But its like using an sledgehammer to kill a gnat. There are better tools on every platform for doing web development, IMHO.